# Aliasing a setter method

Tags: ruby

```
class Test
  attr_accessor :something
end

class Test
  alias :old_something= :something=
  def something=(a)
    a += 2              # do something with the argument
    old_something=(a)   # then pass it on
  end
end
```

I would expect that if I said

```
t = Test.new
t.something = 3
puts t.something
```

It would print out `5`. But it prints `nil`. Why does this not work?

Comment: As the question sits now, it doesn't print out 5, it doesn't print out nil, but something that looks like #<;Test:0x9aa4340>

Comment: I have fixed the example.

Comment: Great, now the problem will show in the example.  And my answer and example is now accurate below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form

```
foo = bar
```

assigns to a local variable. You need to make it explicit that you want to call a method:

```
self.foo = bar
```

Comment: Somehow I missed this obvious point in my answer.  I'll leave my answer there since it may address other concerns.

Comment: Ah, yes that was the problem. I got bit by this problem several times before but forgot about it again.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: @Jörg's answer is probably the real problem, but my original answer below may be helpful as well.  Redacted some misleading details from my old answer.**

If you drop the `def something=` entirely, you'll get a setter for `something` which has an alias of `old_something`:

```
class Test
  attr_accessor :something
end

class Test
  alias :old_something= :something=
end


1.9.3p327 :001 > require "./test.rb"
=> true
1.9.3p327 :002 > t = Test.new
=> #<Test:0x000000018eb740>
1.9.3p327 :003 > t.something = "blah"
=> "blah"
1.9.3p327 :004 > t.something
=> "blah"
1.9.3p327 :005 > t.old_something = "moo"
=> "moo"
1.9.3p327 :006 > t.something
=> "moo"
```

Comment: I am aliasing the setter because I want to do some value checks before passing it on. I guess I should include that in the question to narrow down possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that @something is never assigned to anything.

This code will do what you are trying to do:

```rb
class Test
  attr_accessor :something
end

class Test
  alias :old_something= :something=
  def something=(a)
    @something = a += 2 # do something with the argument
    old_something=(a)   # then pass it on
  end
end

t = Test.new
t.something=( 3)
puts t.something
```

The difference was assinging the instance variable @something to a value, and then allowing your code to increment it by the `a` variable that was passed in.